# How can I call my Python function in my javaScript file?

Tags: javascript, python, dbutils

I want to use my Python function in JavaScript. Obviously, my code is more complicated than demonstrated below, but this is the smallest base on which I was able to replicate the problem:

main.mjs

```
dbutils.notebook.run("./aPythonFile.py", 5, {"parameter1": "helloWorld"})
```

aPythonFile.py:

```
def my_python_function(parameter1):
    print(parameter1)
```

Error message:

> ReferenceError: dbutils is not defined
> at file:///c:/Users/q612386/Dev/SkillUp/SUPAC23-53/Python%20+%20JavaScript%20(ohne%20Listener%20oder%20API)/scripts/tempCodeRunnerFile.js:1:1
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Changing .mjs to .js did not fix the problem.

I am sure it is just a weird import error but I can't seem to find it. Any other simple solution to call a python function in JavaScript is very welcome, too (except for Flask or django).

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you define (import?) `dbutils`?

Comment: The `dbutils` object you are trying to use in your `main.mjs` script seems to be specific to a certain environment, likely Databricks, which is not available in a standard Node.js or browser environment. This is why you're encountering the `ReferenceError: dbutils is not defined` error.

Comment: @David I don't. I am so lost, I don't know what to import. import {run} from dbutils.notebook or import {notebooks.run} from dbutils does not do anything

Comment: @imanMohammadi I see. What can I do in this case then?

Comment: you can use the child processor of spawn to execute python files in js

Comment: @NodeDeveloper I tried that. I wrote in main.mjs:
import {spawn} from "child_process"
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["./aPythonfile.py"]);

in aPythonFile.py:
print("This is magic")

Does not work, though. Unfortunately. How do I make that work?

Comment: @codingCode 
const pythonProcess = spawn('python', [pathOFpythonFile, dynamicValue]);
you can access the argument from python file like this 
```
import sys

# Receive arguments from Node.js
arg_from_node = sys.argv[1]
print("Argument received from Node.js:", arg_from_node)
```

Comment: @nodeDeveloper thanks. It says index out of range, though.

Comment: @codingCode check python is installed in your system or not by using this cmd
python --version
 if not then install then try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256030/discussion-between-node-developer-and-codingcode).

Answer (score 1):

## script.py

```
import sys

# Receive arguments from Node.js
arg_from_node = sys.argv[1]
print("Argument received from Node.js:", arg_from_node)

# Your Python code here...
```

## node_script.js

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Path to your Python script
const pythonScript = 'path/to/script.py';

// Dynamic value from Node.js
const dynamicValue = 'Hello from Node.js';

// Spawn a child process
const pythonProcess = spawn('python3', [pythonScript, dynamicValue]);

// Listen for data from the Python script
pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Python Output: ${data}`);
});

// Listen for any errors from the Python script
pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`Error from Python: ${data}`);
});

// Listen for the process to exit
pythonProcess.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`Python process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```